# Unable to show SSRS Report from a nother page using Report Viewer WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-server, reporting-services, report-viewer

I am using the Report Viewer WebPart to show a .rdl report from another page but the error saying that it cannot find the report.

Error:

> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException:
>   The item'https://domain.com/services/Report.rdl' cannot be found.

Now, my understanding is that the ReportViewer cannot display a report from another source unless the report is within the same page/domain.

Is there another way around or am I left with no options?

Comment: anybody may have a clue or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As a workaround, I had to add a "Subreport" within the .rdl file pointing to another source of .rdl file and that solved my issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Was  the source from another domain? If yes, did you set trust between the domain with SharePoint default domain?

Check whether the web part could work if the source is from the default SharePoint domain.

You need to make sure the followings:
1. SSRS service is started in your farm and your web application is connected to SSRS service application.
2. Report Server Integration Feature is activated in your site collection.

A similar blog for your reference:
[SSRS - “The item '.rdl' cannot be found. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '.rsds' cannot be found” in multi server SharePoint farm](http://dinushaonline.blogspot.com/2015/04/ssrs-item-cannot-be-found.html)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am not the SP Admin to know the in-depth details but from my understanding it may be they are two different domains but on the same FARM? The main domain being eg.  home.domain.com and the source (Where report is based) is at services.domain.com  >> so I assume they are classed two different domains. Where would I add the trust between them two ??